# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't compile with @ symbols in folder names

Tags: visual-studio

"4>CSC : error CS2011: Error opening response file '\xxSomePathxxx\yyMyProjectyy\Framework\@Core\Controllers-BackEnd\AdminCartController.Orders.cs'"

The actual path is "@Framework\@Core", however it seems to be trying to remove the first @ and look for just "Framework\@Core".  I don't know why.

If I remove the @ from the beginning of the @Framework folder name (which is a first level folder in the project), it will compile.  I also tried renaming the @Framework to @SomeFolder thinking maybe framework was reserved.  Its the leading @ symbol.  If I remove it, it compiles.  If I put it back, again with errors for EVERY file in that folder.

Its perfectly happy with @ in folder names below the first tier.  But not happy with them at all in the first tier.

The reason for putting the @ in there is so these specific folders will sort to the top of the solution explorer.  Its perfectly happy with folders beginning with underscore characters (_) which I used for other folders because I wanted them under the @ named folders.  Not @ though.

Is the @ a reserved character and are there others?  Where is this documented if they are?

Comment: The `@` sign is a special character in MsBuild, it is used to pass a reference to the items in an ItemGroup. I've never used an @ in a folder name before, but I can imagine it could cause issues. You can escape the @ with `%40` in the `.csproj` file to see if that fixes it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx)

Comment: This may be a bug in the C# compiler's msbuild targets. The safest solution would be to use a different prefix, preferably one that isn't a reserved character.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a1fs1tb.aspx

Comment: Thank you both.  The .csproj already has it escaped as %40.

Well, I would think it might well be a bug.  Nowhere on that page does it say anything about a folder name containing an @.  Just file  .RSP.  Only thing I can come up with is maybe its misinterpreting it in command line parameters.

The odd part is that it accepts them in sub-folder names.  Just not top tier folder names.  Riddle me that one Batman!

Answer (score 0):

All Credit to @jessehouwing - this is his answer. I just am posting to help the next guy...

The @ sign is a special character in MsBuild, it is used to pass a reference to the items in an ItemGroup.

You can escape the @ with **%40** in the .csproj file to see if that fixes it. (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx) –
jessehouwing

So the current bootstrap link for the Bootstrap Popper (which is what brought me here as they have decided to start a folder with an @ sign) becomes:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/%40@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```